# EF Core and Lookup table with multiple columns

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, razor, entity, lookup

I have the following entities as follows:

```
public class ParentOfAddress
{
    public long HouseId;
    -- some other properties
    public HouseAddress address;
}

public class HouseAddress
{
    public long HouseId;
    public string Line1;
    public string Line2;
    public int CityId;
 
    [NotMapped]
    public string CityName;
    [NotMapped]
    public string ProvCode;
    [NotMapped]
    public string CountryCode;
}

public class City
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string ProvCode;
    public string CountryCode;
}
```

I don't want to ever insert/update entity City.  It is just a Lookup Table that is referenced by CityId.  I don't want add a reference to a Navigation property because I always want to access CityName, ProvCode, CountryCode from the HouseAddress entity.  I can easily do this doing a join and a select new and assigning the lookup names to the HouseAddress entity.  However, the HouseAddress entity is a child of another entity and I don't want to repeat this select multitle times and the ParentOfAddress and HouseAddress need to be updated and inserted at the same time.  I understand that there are multiple ways to handle this issue but why on earth is there a not a simple relationship to define a lookup Entity without having to write the necessary Linq query.  I just want to map the CityName/ProvCode/CountryCode properties from the City entity to the HouseAddress class and I don't really need a reference to the City entity from the HouseAddress entity.
When updating/inserting HouseAddress, I just want to save the CityId.

I can get the result I want by joing the HouseAddress and City entities and selecting the columns but I just wanted to know if there was a way to do this using EF Core Fluent api.  I also have to write the Linq query to lookup the CityId in HouseAddress before an insert/or update. of the HouseAddress parent entity.  I can try the Entity split approach but that would save both the HouseAddress and City entities which is not what I want.  It is more elegant to access the CityName/ProvCode/CountryCode from the HouseAddress model in the Razor pages instead of using HouseAddress.City.Name.  The Razor page for Inserting parent of HouseAddress needs to access the HouseAddress.CityName property and not the HouseAddress.City.Name property since the City entity was never retrieved.  I don't really want to use HouseAddress.CityName sometimes and HouseAddress.City.Name at other times.  This is a simple database design pattern and there must be a simple way to do this.  It is like a computed property that needs to be accessed from another Entity.  Please don't tell me to write code that will save the City.Name property to the HouseAddress.CityName and then set the City property to Null; that is if I actually had a City navigation property.

Comment: A Navigation property would do this automatically for you. You can then use read-only properties to access the nested information: `public string CityName => Address?.CityName;`

Comment: Yes, I know a navigation property will work.  The property CityName belongs with the Address entity and it is retrieved from the City Entity.  Hence, I assume you mean CityName => City?.Name.  This is what I'm using but I wanted to know if there is another way without having to load the City entity as a navigation property of the HouseAddress entity.  If there is no Fluent API that does the property mapping, then I will continue to use this method.